# SSRS - group by on top of page

Tags: service, reporting

in Reporting Services when we group by one column we get the group in the left of the detail. Is it possible to make that group by in the top, just like in Crystal Reports?

Page 1:
Invoice A - name A (on top of page)
Detail 1
Detail 2

Page 2:
Invoice B - name B (on top of page)
Detail 1
Detail 2

I can only get
Invoice A - name A - Detail 1
Invoice A - name A - Detail 2
Invoice B - name B - Detail 1
Invoice B - name B - Detail 2

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this to work, but it's a pain.

- First, make sure that your table is set to page break after every group.
- Click on the box in the table that has the info you want to move to the top of the field (the name, the invoice, whatever) and get its name.
- Wherever you want that data (i.e. in the page header), add a textbox whose value is =First(ReportItems![name].Value).

Unfortunately, that will leave you with the group heading still also present in the table. That's not necessarily a bad thing.

If you want to completely do away with that:

- Stick your whole page in a List control, also set to page break after this element.
- Set the List to group by invoice/name/whatever
- Do the same as in the first option for the header
- Put the table inside the list, with all grouping turned off. I can't remember right now whether you have to manually tell it to use the List's dataset; try the default first and see if it works.